# Why must a struct value be mutable to set an indexed property?

Tags: f#

Consider the following program:

```
[<Struct>]
type Grid2D<'T> = 
    val RowLength : int
    val Data : 'T[]
    new(rowLength, data) = { RowLength = rowLength; Data = data }

    member this.Item
        with get(rowIndex, columnIndex) = 
            this.Data.[rowIndex * this.RowLength + columnIndex]
        and set(rowIndex, columnIndex) value = 
            this.Data.[rowIndex * this.RowLength + columnIndex] <- value

let g = Grid2D(3, Array.zeroCreate(3 * 3))
g.[1, 1] <- 4
```

The last line fails to compile with:

> error FS0256: A value must be mutable in order to mutate the contents
>   or take the address of a value type, e.g. 'let mutable x = ...'

However, if the `[<Struct>]` attribute is removed, and Grid2D is thus a reference type, then the program compiles.

Interestingly, inlining the property setter by hand also compiles fine:

```
g.Data.[1 * g.RowLength + 1] <- 4
```

So why is calling it a compile error?

Note: I am aware that this compiler error exists to make it impossible to mutate a non-mutable value of a struct by setting one of its fields. But I'm clearly not mutating the struct here.

Comment: Whilst I don't know why the struct part is disallowed, themanual method should always work, as your are taking the array out of the struct and array elements are always mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably impossible the compiler could consistently prove any setter doesn't actually mutate the struct, so it doesn't bother and just always emits the error when using assignment statements on non-mutable struct bindings.

In other words the question becomes: *why does F# assume property setters mutate their instance*? Well, probably because that's usually what property setters do.

Inlining the property setter works in this case because then the target of the assignment is an element of a property and not a property of the struct itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess here that its the second part of that error message that applies - "or take the address of a value type". Its not the mutability but the **address** of the value type that needs to be taken in order for you to refer to the same value g when mutating the Data.

Comment: But the get accessor works on non-mutable values - doesn't it need to take the address of the struct too?